# Logical form of a set-theoretic statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic

From Velleman's 'How to Prove it' book, there is one statement - written below - of which I don't know how to write the logical form of, and I'm wondering if somebody could write it out.

The statement is:

" Prove that there is a unique $A\in\mathscr{P}(U)$ such that for every $B\in\mathscr{P}(U), A\cup B = B)$ "

I know it must be in the form $\exists{!xP(x)}$ (and of course I understand that there are different ways to cash out this statement in its full form) but I'm confused as to what represents the $P(x)$ in this case. My guess for the 'existence' part of the formula is:

$\exists{A}(A\in\mathscr{P}(U)\land \forall{B}(B\in\mathscr{P}(U) \land A\cup{B}=B))$

I know I need to do the uniqueness part as well, but I'm not even sure if this is right in the first place.

**EDIT**: Sorry I meant to put a conditional where the second conjunction symbol is. So:

$\exists{A}(A\in\mathscr{P}(U)\land \forall{B}(B\in\mathscr{P}(U) \to A\cup{B}=B))$

However I don't know if this is still correct for the 'existence' part of the formula, though that was what I meant to write.

Comment: It must be : $∀B (B ∈ \mathcal P(U) \to A∪B=B)$. See [Restricted quantifier](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Restricted_quantifier).

Comment: I meant to put a material implication there before, stupid mistake. But is the rest of the existence part of the formula correct?

Comment: @Cp3Shadow Yes what you have in your comment is correct.

Comment: Can you write out what the 'uniquess' part of the formula looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Uniqueness part (in words): For all $A_1,A_2 \in \mathscr{P}(U)$, if { [for all $B$ ($B \in \mathscr{P}(U)$ implies $A_1 \cup B = A_1$] and [for all $B$ ($B \in \mathscr{P}(U)$ implies $A_2 \cup B = A_2$] } then $A_1 = A_2$.

Now to symbolize this is direct.